# DEFAULT CONSTRAINT full form

Tags: sql-server, constraints, default, default-constraint

For each table constraint, I see that there are *shorthand* form, *semi-shorthand* form and *full* form (Pardon me for the naming. Suggestions of how to correctly call them are welcome)

For example

Shorthand form: let constraint name be defined by SQL Server, column to be affected is implied as the column being defined

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
)
```

Semi-shorthand form: explicit constraint name, implied column

```
id int CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY,
```

Full form : both explicit. Allow definition at the end separated from column definition

```
id int,
Name varchar(40),
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

From what I see, the full form is seen often in `ALTER TABLE`, where constraints are defined afterwards.

For `DEFAULT` constraint

Short-hand form

```
id int DEFAULT newid()
```

Semi-shorthand form

```
id int CONSTRAINT DF_ID DEFAULT newid()
```

I see a full-form use in `ALTER TABLE` as [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912(v=sql.80).aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
  CONSTRAINT [DF__Customers__cust___151B244E] 
  DEFAULT ('new customer') FOR [cust_name],
  CONSTRAINT [def_last_updated_by] DEFAULT 
  (suser_sname()) FOR [last_updated_by],
  PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
  ([cust_id])  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

However, full-form definition when creating table fails

```
CREATE TABLE testGUIDs
(
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    Name varchar(40),
    CONSTRAINT DF_ID DEFAULT newid() FOR [ID]
)
GO
```

with an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'for'.

Can anyone suggest why this error occurs and how to use full-form definition of Default constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the syntax of a default constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` command is different to that in `ALTER TABLE`. Just because a command uses one syntax you cannot assuming it is the same for all commands.

In a [CREATE TABLE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) command the syntax requires a constraint with a default to be defined after the column:

```
<column_definition> ::=column_name <data_type>
...
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] DEFAULT constant_expression ] 
...
```

With the constant_expression defined as:

> Is a constant, NULL, or a system function that is used as the default
>   value for the column.

But in the [ALTER TABLE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) the syntax is:

```
...
| ADD <table_constraint> 
...
```

The syntax of the [table_contraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) is:

```
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
{ 
    ...
    | DEFAULT constant_expression FOR column [ WITH VALUES ] 
    ...
}
```

A number of changes can be defined in a single `ALTER TABLE` command, so the column name needs to be specified.

So there is no "full form" syntax for `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it next to the column

```
CREATE TABLE testGUIDs
(
    ID uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT DF_ID DEFAULT newid(),
    Name varchar(40)    
)
GO
```

A default constraint can only apply to a single column.

The grammar for [`table_constraint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) doesn't include `Default` which would allow it to be declared at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1. `id int PRIMARY KEY` can only be applied to a single-field PK. The constraint is given a default name by the system. This is a problem if you need the name later in order to manipulate the constraint and you don't know the name.
2. `id int CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY` can only be applied to a single-field PK.
3. `CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2)` can be applied to compound primary keys.

As for your problem: Why not use the inline variant? A default constraint can only be applied to a single column anyway. Your syntax is simply not supported.